# What does 6 represent in Medieval Welsh?

Tags: transcription, welsh

In both [*A Glossary of Mediaeval Welsh Law*](https://archive.org/details/glossaryofmediae00lewiuoft/page/172/mode/1up) (1913, Timothy Lewis) and [*Early Welsh Gnomic Poems*](https://archive.org/details/earlywelshgnomic00jack/page/60/mode/1up) (1935 ed. Kenneth Jackson) you can find the numeral 6 used (apparently) to represent a vowel. Can anyone explain this?

I’m guessing it might be representing some particular form in the manuscript. Luckily for my Google-fu, this same example appears in both (pages linked above):

> *a phan edrych6yt ar y dyle nyt oed arnei namyn byrwellt dysdlyt ch6einllyt a boneu g6rysc yn amyl tr6yda6,…*

**Edit:** After Yellow Sky’s answer I found that this and some other characters exist in Unicode.

- Ỻ U+1EFA LATIN CAPITAL LETTER MIDDLE-WELSH LL
- ỻ U+1EFB LATIN SMALL LETTER MIDDLE-WELSH LL
- Ỽ U+1EFC LATIN CAPITAL LETTER MIDDLE-WELSH V
- ỽ U+1EFD LATIN SMALL LETTER MIDDLE-WELSH V

> *a phan edrychỽyt ar y dyle nyt oed arnei namyn byrweỻt dysdlyt chỽeinỻyt a boneu gỽrysc yn amyl trỽydaỽ,…*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is obvious that **6** stands for the modern letter **w** which in Welsh can be pronounced in some words as the consonant [w] and in other words as vowels [ʊ] or [uː]. In your example there is the word *byrwellt* in which **w** is the consonant [w], while **6** in your example stands where **w** is a vowel letter. 
Your example is from [*Breuddwyd Rhonabwy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dream_of_Rhonabwy) ("The Dream of Rhonabwy"), a Middle Welsh prose tale, [here](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=LsJgqSFFqkkC&pg=PA373&lpg=PA373&dq=edrychwyt&source=bl&ots=URRmyh19Qa&sig=ACfU3U2T-vKJuQppbM9OlAUA6yyFNZpDmg&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjwkc71g9TnAhXrtYsKHXBcBvIQ6AEwAnoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=edrychwyt&f=false) your example text is printed with **w**s instead of the **6**s.

Frankly speaking, it is the first time I have seen such usage of **6**, and have no idea why they did it so.

**UPDATE:** I have just found an explanation in [this book](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=kxM0EON_J_EC&pg=PA151&lpg=PA151&dq=%226%20for%20w%22%20welsh&source=bl&ots=-lZlLvvpN0&sig=ACfU3U2yMfc0jU5t6xbGX_p85TBqvh98Rw&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFxqeii9TnAhXzwsQBHdyCCrMQ6AEwAHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%226%20for%20w%22%20welsh&f=false), in the very bottom of the page in a footnote:

> Transcriptions of Welsh often use '6' for 'w' which reflects the form of the letter found in the manuscripts.

The next page of the book contains a passage in Welsh in which most of **w**s are written as **6**s.

**UPDATE 2:** Here is a page from [*The Red Book of Hergest*](https://reginajeffers.blog/2014/10/17/the-red-book-of-hergest-welsh-medieval-manuscript/) (Welsh: *Llyfr Coch Hergest*), a large vellum manuscript written shortly after 1382, where I highlighted some of the instances of **w** written as **6**:

[image]

Comment: Interesting! Was there any connection between this form of *w* and the number six? Or is the numeral written differently in these manuscripts?

Comment: @Draconis - This very manuscript has both pages and columns numbered with the digit **6** looking just as we write it now, while in the 6-looking W's the circle is not completely closed. The full color hi-rez images of [_The Red Book of Hergest_ online](https://digital.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/inquire/p/9bf187bf-f862-4453-bc4f-851f6d3948af).

Comment: Good to know, thank you!

Comment: Thank you! I see that there are actually some Unicode characters for Middle-Welsh as well: Ỻ ỻ Ỽ ỽ. The Unicode Consortium call this letter LATIN SMALL LETTER MIDDLE-WELSH V.